# unable to push master heroku PHP app (worked yesterday)

Tags: git, heroku, push

I am trying to push a PHP app.  It worked fine yesterday.  Today it throws errors.  The error of Submodule path 'sdk' may have something to do with it, but as I said, no big changes since yesterday aside from some minor code tweaks!

```
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:everyvotematters benjamin$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'everyvotematters/master' by 4 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:everyvotematters benjamin$ git push everyvotematters master
Counting objects: 24, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 4.49 KiB, done.
Total 20 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Git submodules detected, installing
       Submodule 'sdk' (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk.git) registered for path 'sdk'
       Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/build_awiw4oll8o2g/sdk/.git/
       Submodule path 'sdk': checked out '98f2be163c96a51166354e467b95dd38aa4b0a19'
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:everyvotematters.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:everyvotematters.git'
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:everyvotematters benjamin$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a local version of the SDK folder. This was fine, then one day it just up and quit working on me.

First copy your SDK folder somehwere safe then run:

```
git rm sdk
git commit -am "removing sdk folder"
git push heroku master
```

Then I copy the folder back in, reran the commit and push commands
This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, the "no Cedar-supported app detected" is curious.  I suspect you've modified your app in such a way that there's no longer an `index.php` in the root folder?  That's how Heroku detects it's a PHP app.